# Windows IME Chinese blocking shortcut for ctrl + space

Tags: keyboard, customization, windows

I currently use the Windows IME on Windows Vista to allow myself to type Chinese characters (not in *Mathematica*), and by default typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> switches between the English keyboard and the Chinese keyboard. When in Mathematica, I would like to use the default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to move out of subscripts and superscripts.

Is it possible to retain the functionality of this keyboard shortcut in Mathematica? I cannot figure out how to remove the shortcut from the IME, which is an acceptable solution, since i do not use this shortcut to switch languages.

Comment: I end up not using this shortcut in MMA. Totally give up LOL

Comment: Even disabling all shortcuts, the keyboard just do what he wants, Windows is still a 3 year old baby. Lot's of work ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS interface for modifying the key strokes is buggy and does not correctly read and write the registry keys where the input method is held. Try removing the shortcut and press [Apply] to see this in action. The keyboard shortcuts CTRL+SPACE are only on the two Chinese languages by default. There are guides online for how to edit the registry keys directly to fix this specific issue. I guess it's a bonus feature!

Comment: After doing further research, I confirmed that (at least for my windows version) you are correct. I changed the registry key on my work computer and the fixed worked. I am still trying to get it to work on my laptop, which I assume is giving me trouble due to a different version of Windows (7 versus Vista).

Answer (score 5):

It seems your Windows system works differently than mine (Win7-64). I don't believe I can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> combo, but I know how to change the setting:

Right click on the language symbol in the task bar

[image]

Select Settings from the pop-up menu, in the resulting dialog box pick the 3rd tab

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Select the action by clicking on a keyboard name, and pressing the "Change Key Sequence" button. You get either this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

dialog box where you can select the key sequence you want or deselect it, as it seems that that is what you want.

Comment: Your answer seems to give me exactly what I want, but for some reason I cannot disable the key sequence. I also tried changing the shortcut to another key binding that I do not use, but the ctrl+space combination remains active. I do not want this to become further off topic from Mathematica so I will accept this answer and ask on another forum.

Comment: @Carl Actually on Windows cycling through input languages (Left Alt Shift by default) is a separate function from switching between a Chinese and a non-Chinese language (Ctrl Space by default).  That's why this didn't work.